# how to get max(date) from given set of data grouped by some fields using pyspark?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the data in the dataframe as below:

```
  datetime             | userId | memberId | value |    
2016-04-06 16:36:...   | 1234   | 111      | 1
2016-04-06 17:35:...   | 1234   | 222      | 5
2016-04-06 17:50:...   | 1234   | 111      | 8
2016-04-06 18:36:...   | 1234   | 222      | 9
2016-04-05 16:36:...   | 4567   | 111      | 1
2016-04-06 17:35:...   | 4567   | 222      | 5
2016-04-06 18:50:...   | 4567   | 111      | 8
2016-04-06 19:36:...   | 4567   | 222      | 9
```

I need to find the max(datetime) groupby userid,memberid. When I tried as below:

```
df2 = df.groupBy('userId','memberId').max('datetime')
```

I'm getting error as:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: "datetime" is not a numeric
column. Aggregation function can only be applied on a numeric column.;
```

The output I desired is as follows:

```
userId | memberId | datetime
1234   |  111     | 2016-04-06 17:50:...
1234   |  222     | 2016-04-06 18:36:...
4567   |  111     | 2016-04-06 18:50:...
4567   |  222     | 2016-04-06 19:36:...
```

Can someone please help me how I get the max date among the given data using PySpark dataframes?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For non-numeric but `Orderable` types you can use `agg` with `max` directly:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, max as max_

df = sc.parallelize([
    ("2016-04-06 16:36", 1234, 111, 1),
    ("2016-04-06 17:35", 1234, 111, 5),
]).toDF(["datetime", "userId", "memberId", "value"])

(df.withColumn("datetime", col("datetime").cast("timestamp"))
    .groupBy("userId", "memberId")
    .agg(max_("datetime")))

## +------+--------+--------------------+
## |userId|memberId|       max(datetime)|
## +------+--------+--------------------+
## |  1234|     111|2016-04-06 17:35:...|
## +------+--------+--------------------+
```

Comment: How can I calculate the max (date) and min(date) of a date column?  The column type is DateType(). Thanks! @zero323

Comment: @ElsaLi `from pyspark.sql.functions import  min as min_;  df.withColumn.groupBy(...).agg(min_("datetime"), max_("datetime"))`

Comment: Is there a reason why we need to use the `_` instead of just  ```max('datetime')``` ?

Comment: @thentangler the max_ is an alias of the max funtion from pyspark itself (see import statement in code). If you would just do max('datetime'), it would use the python function 'max' which was not made to work with columns.

Comment: @zero323 , @Lennart : why did it remove the column `value` from the original df?

Comment: @zero323 , @Lennart : How to keep the column `value` from the original df?

Comment: @BigDataLearner Also ran into this issue. Think that here it's explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409875/how-to-get-other-columns-when-using-spark-dataframe-groupby

Comment: @user2177768 thanks for pointing it out, is it possible to retain the column `value` without doing a join with the original df

Comment: @BigDataLearner did you find your answer?