# How to filter to max date in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to filter my dataframe to only keep rows with max value in column `some_date`.

`df.filter(F.col('some_date') = F.max('some_date'))` fails, as max is not used in aggregate.

I also tried to just get the max_date value to then use it in filter: `max_date = df.groupBy().max('some_date')`, which failed telling me that `"some_date" is not a numeric column. Aggregation function can only be applied on a numeric column.`

In SQL, I would achieve this with a subquery (to the effect of `where some_date = (select max(some_date) from ...`), but I thought there would be a better way to structure it in Python.

Comment: df.groupby().agg({"some_date":"max"}).show() ??

Comment: I think you want an aggregate window over dates https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-functions-windows.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [how to get max(date) from given set of data grouped by some fields using pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38377894/10465355)