# How to Merge Spark Scala Dataframe - Multiple rows into One based on condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Dataframe 1:

```
12345,B,C,2020-08-12,Internet
12345,B,D,2002-11-12,Mobile
12345,B,e,2003-10-12,Lap
```

Dataframe 2

```
12345
```

I have to join Dataframe 1 and Dataframe 2 and produce 1 row per record in the output for each record in DF2. My output should be like below,

Output:

```
12345,Y,Y,2002-11-12,Mobile
```

Conditions for columns,

Col 1 - Distinct value

Col 2 - If **ALL** values in col2 of DF1 == 'B', then populate 'Y' in output else 'N'

Col 3 - If **ANY** value in col3 of DF1 == 'C', then populate 'Y' in output else 'N'

Col 4 - Take Min date from col4 of DF1

Col 5 - Populate the value corresponding to Min date from Col 5 of DF1

How to achieve this?

Comment: can you make clrearer exemple and explanation?

Comment: can you please explain it a little clear? ... as per my understading your output should be 12345,Y,N . I'm i correct?

Comment: I have added a clear explanation.. Could you please suggest now

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve it by using **groupBy** then **agg** API.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implictis._
val dataframe2 = dataframe1.groupBy("_c0")
 .agg(when(size(array_distinct(collect_list('_c1))) === lit("1") and array_contains(array_distinct(collect_list('_c1)),'B'),lit("Y")).otherwise(lit("N"))
 ,when(array_contains(collect_list('_c1),'C'),lit("Y")).otherwise(lit("N"))
 ,min('_c3).alias("date"))
```

**Then join `dataframe2.join(dataframe1,Seq("_c0","dateColumn"),"inner")`** and select all columns from `dataframe2(select(dataframe2("*")))` and select only `dataframe1(dataframe1("_c4"))` you will get the desired result...

***note : make sure to alias properly dataframe2 and dataframe1 columns before joining***

In [group by and aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409875/how-to-get-other-columns-when-using-spark-dataframe-groupby), you cannot access normal columns of parent DF.

***Otherwise*** :
you can convert your dataframe to [rdd](https://data-flair.training/blogs/spark-rdd-operations-transformations-actions/#:%7E:text=Spark%20Transformation%20is%20a%20function,RDD%20are%20immutable%20in%20nature.) and then convert **rdd to pairedRdd<Key,Object>** then you can perform [reduceByKey or aggregateByKey or groupByKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364432/spark-difference-between-reducebykey-vs-groupbykey-vs-aggregatebykey-vs-combineb) operations on paired RDD and calculate all aggregations by writing custom code.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Could you please let me know how to modify the .agg function for the changes I have added now

Comment: Hi, when you do countDistinct('_c1) === lit(1), if all the values in c1 is 'B' the result will be okay, but I need to set 'Y' only if it is 'B'. There are chances where _c1 will have all 'J" in that column. So taking countdistinct will not work since it will return 1 and condition gets satisfied but really it should not. I need to the check the values of the _c1 whether it is equal to 'B'

Comment: If possible code snippet pls? Or any example of how it is done.

Comment: @muralikrishna please check the edited solution. I have addressed your issues

Comment: if you want to do it in rdd way which is specified in otherwise part ... you need to explore rdd apis and transformation i have provided enough resources link for you. please go ahead

Comment: ok thank you. I cannot import array_distinct as I'm using spark 2.1 and array_distinct was introduced in 2.4.. any other alternatives for it?